# String to byte not working and generate PDF

Tags: c#

When

```cs
byte[] bytes = {105,122,101,32 ......... 105,122,101,32}
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("E:\\hello-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssff") + ".pdf", bytes);
```

this work

---

```cs
string data = "105,122,101,32 ......... 105,122,101,32"
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data );
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("E:\\hello-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssff") + ".pdf", bytes);
```

not work

why can't i convert string to byte well?
Thanks

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` doesn't convert a string containing a sequence of comma-delimited numbers into bytes based on those numbers, it's literally converting each *character* to its byte-value according to the ASCII encoding. You will need to parse that string and extract the numbers, then convert those to bytes.

Comment: Why do you have `string data = "105,122,101,32,..."`? Why do you have a string that consists of comma-separated integers? If you want to parse that to bytes, you'll have to split your string on comma, and parse each value as byte. What your code currently does, is getting the byte values of the Unicode code points converted to ASCII, so `'1', '0', '5', ',', '1', '2', ...` becomes `49, 48, 53, 44, 49, 50, ...`. But you really should not have that string to begin with.

Comment: And by "not work" I assume the code is executing, but the PDF file it is creating is not readable by PDF clients. If "not work" means something else, please clarify what you mean.

Comment: So just to clarify, string to byte array via `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` **is** working, exactly as it is designed, it's just that it wasn't designed to do what you expected it to do.

Comment: I also get the string in json and yvcberber only the one that I am working on PDF, it's already there with commas

Comment: Whoever wrote that JSON needs some quiet words; usually, you'd embed that into JSON as a base-64 string

Comment: Again, _why_ do you have that string? It expands the size to almost 400%. It is a nonsensical way of data transfer. If you'd use base64, it'd be 133%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK; so the problem here is that *for whatever reason*, you have a comma-separated string that contains the bytes as integers, and you need to parse that into bytes. Horrible (base-64 would be a far better choice), but: fine: simply *do that*. This is not pretty, but should work fine:

```cs
string data = ...
var bytes = Array.ConvertAll(data.Split(','), byte.Parse);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("E:\\hello-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssff") + ".pdf", bytes);
```